# Android application launching from console

Tags: java, android, c++, apk

Is it possible to make a console Android app using the Android API? This application must be hidden in the package manager. Can you give me examples? In C++/Java.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want a console in Android so that you can type in java commands? If so, then no is the answer. Android does not have the option to use reflection. And reflection is needed to create a virtual machine where you can execute commands.

Comment: I need an application which must be launch from terminal and it been working in the background (service). It must be hidden in app list and package manager.

Answer (score 0):

> The NDK is a toolset that allows you to implement parts of your app
>   using native-code languages such as C and C++. For certain types of
>   apps, this can be helpful so you can reuse existing code libraries
>   written in these languages, but most apps do not need the Android NDK.

http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

I think this is what you're looking for, but as the description says, make sure it's what you really need.